# Cannot switch on a value of type String for source level below 1.7. Only convertible int values or enum variables are permitted

Tags: java, java-8, switch-statement

The error shows up on statment

```
switch(req) //req is a string
```

But I am using `jdk 1.8`

Comment: You've configured your IDE to use the Java 5 or Java 6 (or maybe even older) language level. Change that. You're not saying what your IDE is so...

Comment: @JBNizet using netbeans 8.2

Comment: Not using this IDE, but here's whet a google search for "Netbeans source level" returns: https://blogs.oracle.com/roumen/netbeans-quick-tip-1-setting-target-jdk